# ¿Como puedo detectar que hubo un error al conectarse a una wifi?

Tags: android

En mi aplicación te pido que te conectes a una red wifi, pero hay veces que el usuario pone la contraseña mal pues somos humanos. Quiero que si esto pasa poner un cartel de aviso. Hay alguna forma de saber esto? Debe haber porque el sistema operativo lo detecta. Alguna ayuda? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si es en ionic puedes utilizar esto: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/ sino puedes hacer un ping a google y con la respuesta ya sabes si tienes o no internet

Comment: si pero por ejemplo Messenger el te dice en el momento exacto que te conectas como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: pero conectas a wifi desde tu app? o pones como obligacion que conecten a una red wifi? No lo acabo de entender pero con lo que te he dicho arriba deberías ser capaz de saber si te has conectado o no

Comment: es una aplicación Android y pido en esta que se conecten a una red

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que has tratado, revisar [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iba a poner esto en un comentario pero es muy largo para tal, por lo que lo pongo aqui:

Hasta la API 28 había un int llamado `ERROR_AUTHENTICATING` en la clase `WifiManager`, cuyas docs puedes ver [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#ERROR_AUTHENTICATING).

Si quieres que la app tenga compatibilidad con las versiones más nuevas de android, puedes usar la clase `WifiInfo`, que puedes ver [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo), y usar un codigo tal que este:

```
//Si asi da error de sintaxis, llama a esta funcion utilizando el contexto de la app
//Algo asi: WifiInfo redInfo = getBaseContext().getConnectionInfo();
WifiInfo redInfo = getConnectionInfo();
String WifiSSID = redInfo.getBSSID();
//Si el valor de WifiSSID es "<unknown ssid>" no está conectado/ha fallado la conexion
if(WifiSSID.equals("<unknown ssid>")) {
   //Hacer algo en base al error
} else {
   //No hay error, todo correcto
}
```

Me gustaría recalcar que, segun [las docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) `WifiManager`:

> Esta clase solo debería ser obtenida desde el contexto de la aplicación, no desde otro para evitar perdidas de memoria en el proceso que lo ejecute.

Comment: claro muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: una pregunta como funcionaria con ERROR_AUTHENTICATING en la clase WifiManager me puedes poner algún ejemplo??

Comment: @AlexRivas personalmente no lo recomiendo, ya que es una funcion deprecada, si aun así quiere hacerlo así pruebe con [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328215/retrieve-wifi-connection-statusandroid) o [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527645/android-connecting-to-wifi-wifimanager-supplicant-state-changed-action-strange-i)

Comment: porque esta deprecado??

Comment: Los desarrolladores así lo han decidido, probablemente será porque ahora habrán mejores opciones que usar @AlexRivas

Comment: gracias por la aclaracion